# cakephp data retrieval

Tags: function, cakephp, information-retrieval

I'm trying to create a page that will spit out a users invoices. I am having trouble with the retrieval of specific users invoices. The issue is with the function in the controller and setting the $id. I'm not sure how to set it to the current user.

Here is the relevant code in my function

```
public function payInvoice(){

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Pay Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';
    $userid = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $this->set('Invoices', $this->Invoice->findByBiller($userid));
}
```

This is the answer
included my view:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Biller</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>

                <?php foreach($Invoices as $invoice):?>
                    <tr> 
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $this->Html->link($Invoices['Invoice']['to'], 
                        array('action' => 'viewInvoice', $Invoices['Invoice']['to'])); ;?> </td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $Invoices['Invoice']['subject']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $Invoices['Invoice']['datecreated']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><a href="viewinvoice"><button>View Invoice</button></a><a href="disputeinvoice"><button>Dispute Invoice</button></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </table>
```

in the code I have it hard coded so user 15 can view all his invoices but I don't want my system hard coded. I want it to be set to `$id='currentuser'` but am unsure of how to code it.

users login function

```
 public function login() {


    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Individual Registration');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');

    if ($this->request->is('post')){
    $this->request->data['User']['password'] = 'qazwsx';
   if ($this->Auth->login()) {

       $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('eboxs/home'));
       $this->Session->write('Myid',$myid);
    } 
    else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect');
    }
    }else{
    $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome, please login');
    }


}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is the user_id the id of the user thats logged in?

Comment: no userid is the id of the user logged in

Comment: the id of the user that's logged in is in $this->Auth->user('id');

Comment: tigrang, do i add that code in elsewhere? I'm beyond stuck and am pulling my hair out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For current user you need to have the session, Im assuming the session contains user_id.
Try this

```
public function payInvoice(){
        $id=$this->Session->read('user_id');
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Pay Invoice');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';
        $this->set('Invoices', $this->Invoice->findByBiller($id));
}
```

Comment: which value you want o pass ?

Comment: What is the solution please share

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign a session id with its value to be the user_id?

Comment: would i do that in the app controller?

Comment: Don't need to. just follow what @cutebabs said in her response.

Answer (score 0):

When user sucessfully logged in that time u set his id in session
like,

```
   $this->Session->write('Myid',$myid);
```

`$myid` is fetched from database when username and password is correct

and fetch anywhere in your controller like,

```
   $id = $this->Session->read('Myid');
```

and u don't need to add into app_controller file

Comment: so would i put the first line of code in the users controller, in the login function? then put the second line of code in the invoices controller?

Comment: where the login function u have writeen, i think userscontroller

Comment: i have the login function written in my userscontroller, I'll post it in the original post

Comment: first write session write and then redirect.. and for $myid,  write select query for fetch id from users table where username =  $this->data['User']['txtusername'];